# R ggplot2 list of plots with different timedate format - is that a bug?

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, format

I am trying to produce a list of ggplot2 graphs with different timedate format labels on the x axe. Yet the format argument is not taken into account as expected by ggplot. 
Here is the minimal code that can reproduce the issue.

```
x<-as.POSIXct(strptime(c("2013-01-01 00:00:00","2013-01-02 00:00:00"),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
y1<-c(0,1)
y2<-c(0,-1)
df<-data.frame(x=x,y1=y1,y2=y2)
f<-function(a,b){ggplot(df,aes_string(x="x",y=b))+geom_line()+ scale_x_datetime(labels= date_format(a))}
r<-mapply(f,c("%b-%d","%H:%M"),c("y1","y2"),SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

`r[2]` gives the expected plot (sorry I can not post pictures) but for `r[1]` the axes format is not correct (whereas the data to plot is correctly taken into account).

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between `ggplot` environments and `mapply` and promise evaluation, `a` is not being evaluated appropriately, you can get around this by `force`ing it within the function

eg

```
f<-function(a,b){
  a <- force(a)
  ggplot(df,aes_string(x="x",y=b))+geom_line()+ scale_x_datetime(labels= date_format(a))
}
r <- mapply(f,c("%b-%d","%H:%M"),c("y1","y2"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

r[1]
```

[image]

```
r[2]
```

[image]

[Explain a lazy evaluation quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129902/explain-a-lazy-evaluation-quirk) explains the lazy evalation in more detail.

Comment: That works ! thanks a lot! Do you think this shall be considered as a ggplot bug?

Comment: @user2147028 -- it isn't a bug, more a quirk of lazy evaluation and the way mapply and lapply work