# Explain a lazy evaluation quirk

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I am reading Hadley Wickhams's book on Github, in particular [this part on lazy evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lazy-evaluation). There he gives an example of consequences of lazy evaluation, in the part with `add/adders` functions. Let me quote that bit:

> This [lazy evaluation] is important when creating closures with lapply or a loop:
>
> ```
> add <- function(x) {
>   function(y) x + y
> }
> adders <- lapply(1:10, add)
> adders[[1]](10)
> adders[[10]](10)
> ```
>
> x is lazily evaluated the first time that you call one of the adder
>   functions. At this point, the loop is complete and the final value of
>   x is 10. Therefore all of the adder functions will add 10 on to their
>   input, probably not what you wanted! Manually forcing evaluation fixes
>   the problem:
>
> ```
> add <- function(x) {
>   force(x)
>   function(y) x + y
> }
> adders2 <- lapply(1:10, add)
> adders2[[1]](10)
> adders2[[10]](10)
> ```

I do not seem to understand that bit, and the explanation there is minimal. Could someone please elaborate that particular example, and explain what happens there? I am specifically puzzled by the sentence "at this point, the loop is complete and the final value of x is 10". What loop? What final value, where? Must be something simple I am missing, but I just don't see it. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Note that the answer to this question has changed as of R 3.2.0, see my answer below.

Comment: Complement to @jhin's comment: While `lapply()` has changed in recent R, the function `purrr::map()`, which is intended to be used wherever `lapply()` is, still behaves like the old `lapply()` vis-à-vis shared environments of closures. However, I wouldn't count on this “anachronism” of `purrr::map()` to stick around, as it will likely be rectified in future versions.

Comment: @jhin Actually, I guess hadley's tutorial is built directly from github so reading it after R 3.2.0 is now quite bizarre as that release made the whole section about lazy evaluation in that tutorial moot: there's no more difference with `adders` and `adders2`'s outputs!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The goal of:

```
adders <- lapply(1:10, function(x)  add(x) )
```

is to create a list of `add` functions, the first adds 1 to its input, the second adds 2, etc.  Lazy evaluation causes R to wait for really creating the adders functions until you really start calling the functions. The problem is that after creating the first adder function, `x` is increased by the `lapply` loop, ending at a value of 10. When you call the first adder function, lazy evaluation now builds the function, getting the value of `x`. The problem is that the original `x` is no longer equal to one, but to the value at the end of the `lapply` loop, i.e. 10.

Therefore, lazy evaluation causes all adder functions to wait until after the `lapply` loop has completed in really building the function. Then they build their function with the same value, i.e. 10. The solution Hadley suggests is to force `x` to be evaluated directly, avoiding lazy evaluation, and getting the correct functions with the correct `x` values.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase that to see whether I am getting it right. When we call `lapply`, R sort of remembers the structure of all 10 adder functions, but does not evaluate x yet. When we call the first adder function, R says, aha, let's see what that is, takes x, which already is 10 at that point from the lapply call, and evaluates the first called adder function as 10 + y. Same for the remaining adder functions, rendering them all identical. Probably crudely put, but is that the logic of it?

Comment: I believe that this is case.

Comment: @hadley When I call the first adder function, the lapply loop is already over. Where exactly does the adder function look to find x? Why does the value of x = 10 persists?

Comment: How does the lazy evaluation actually work?  All ten different adder functions each have ten separate environments in which to contain `x`.  I suppose maybe they all point to somewhere prior to getting evaluated, but point to where?  There's no `x` in the parent environment.

Comment: The environment is created when the function is called for the first time. The x variable is equal to 10 at that time after the lapply loop finished. So they are all the same.

Comment: By the way, my example code does not include an x, the example code does. I edited my question to remedy this.

Answer (score 58):

This is no longer true as of R 3.2.0!

The corresponding line in the [change log](http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS) reads:

> Higher order functions such as the apply functions and Reduce() now
>   force arguments to the functions they apply in order to eliminate
>   undesirable interactions between lazy evaluation and variable capture
>   in closures.

And indeed:

```
add <- function(x) {
  function(y) x + y
}
adders <- lapply(1:10, add)
adders[[1]](10)
# [1] 11
adders[[10]](10)
# [1] 20
```