# in R: nest two lists of functions and return combined functions in a list

Tags: r, list, function, functional-programming, nested

I have two lists of functions that I try to combine to one list of functions (one nested in the other).

```
funlist=list()
funlist[[1]] <- function(x1){2*x1}
funlist[[2]] <- function(x2){3*x2}

anotherlist=list()
anotherlist[[1]]=function(y1){0.5*y1}
anotherlist[[2]]=function(y2){0.7*y2}
```

The lists will have the same length. Desired outcome is another function list:

```
finalfun=list()
finalfun[[1]] which shall be the same as funlist[[1]](anotherlist[[1]])
...
```

Hence, if I called
 `finalfun[[1]](6)`, I would get the result "6"  [2*(0.5*6)], similar to calling:

```
 funlist[[1]](anotherlist[[1]](6))
```

I tried the following to create a function that nests two input functions:

```
nestfun <- function(infun,outfun) {lapply(1:length(infun),function(i){outfun[[i]](infun[[i]])})}   
test=nestfun(infun=anotherlist, outfun=funlist)
```

Which produced an error:

```
Error in 2 * x1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
Called from: lapply(1:length(infun), function(i) {
    outfun[[i]](infun[[i]])
})
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: `dput()` is your friend along with this spiffy FAQ on making a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I edited the example above. Now you can reproduce the error. However, the issue is not really the error itself, but rather something wrong in my functional programming approach. One could have seen this even without an "reproducible example" (even though I agree that, if possible, one should always provide one - which is why I re-edited the text).

Comment: See `?mapply`, it will work on two lists "pair-wise".

Comment: Do you have to use anonymous functions at the time of creating the list? Or are you referencing named functions?

Comment: Ben, yes, unfortunately I need anonymous functions (they are closures - functions written by other functions before). Thanks for your help yesterday - as you can see I tried to apply your solution to this case, but unfortunately failed :/

Comment: @Roman Luštrik: mapply did not work either (happy to be proven wrong, but when i tried: nestfun <- function(infun,outfun) {mapply(function(i){outfun[[i]](infun[[i]])},1:length(infun))}, it produced the same error as lapply above

Comment: You can create a function that takes two functions as arguments, and returns a closure that is a composite function of the two input functions. In any case, this is a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
fnest<-function(f1,f2){  
force(f1)
force(f2)
nest<-function(x) f1(f2(x))}

finalfun<-list()
finalfun<-lapply(1:length(funlist), function (i) fnest(funlist[[i]], anotherlist[[i]]) )

finalfun[[2]](10)
#21
```

Note that `finalfun` is a list of closures. The function `fnest` takes two functions as inputs and returns a composite function (a closure).

It's now trivial to create a function that operates on your two function lists:

```
nestfun<-function(funlist,anotherlist){
fnest<-function(f1,f2){  
force(f1)
force(f2)
nest<-function(x) f1(f2(x))}

finalfun<-list()
finalfun<-lapply(1:length(funlist), function (i) fnest(funlist[[i]], anotherlist[[i]]) ) }

finalfun<-list()
finalfun<-nestfun(funlist,anotherlist)
```

EDIT: In case people are curious about the use of `force()`, check out this question on lazy evaluation: [Explain a lazy evaluation quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129902/explain-a-lazy-evaluation-quirk)

Comment: Thanks Ben! Great work - generally, wonder why one has to use force in both solutions (here and mnel's below).

Comment: Lazy evaluation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129902/explain-a-lazy-evaluation-quirk

Comment: Thanks for the link/ additional explanation,Ben!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that uses `Compose` from the functional package. Note, due to lazy evaluation you need to  `force` the arguments

```
library(functional)
Composed <- Map(function(x, y) {
  x <- force(x)
  y <- force(y)
   Compose(y, x)}, 
 funlist,anotherlist)
# A Couple of examples
Composed[[1]](6) 
# [1] 6
Composed[[2]](6)
# [1] 12.6
```

Comment: Thanks mnel! Worked fine. Nice and concise solution (and I learnt about a new package to look at). Forgive me that I decided to accept Ben's answer as the selected solution - I just liked that you do not need another package in his approach.