# Lazy evaluation example in Hadley's "Advanced R" book

Tags: r, function, lazy-evaluation

Hadley's "Advanced R" book contains the following example that I have a hard time understanding.

> ```
> add <- function(x) {
>   function(y) x + y
> }
> adders <- lapply(1:10, add)
> adders[[1]](10)
> #> [1] 20
> adders[[10]](10)
> #> [1] 20
> ```
>
> x is lazily evaluated the first time that you call one of the adder functions. At this point, the loop is complete and the
>   final value of x is 10. Therefore all of the adder functions will add
>   10 on to their input, probably not what you wanted!

I check and it is indeed true that `x` within each `adders[[num]]` evaluates to `10`.

```
get("x", envir=environment(adders[[2]])) # = 10
get("x", envir=environment(adders[[9]])) # = 10
```

But why? For example, when `adders[[2]]` is defined as the returned value of `add(2)`, at that moment `x = 2`. According to Hadley, "a function preserves the environment in which it was defined." So why didn't `adders[[2]]` preserve the environment in which `x = 2`?

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129902/explain-a-lazy-evaluation-quirk

Comment: @rawr Thanks for the link. There's still something I don't understand (I added a comment on the original post). But I'll ask here as well. When I call the first adder function, the lapply loop is already over.  Why does the value of `x = 10` persists? Where exactly does the adder function look to find x?

Comment: there is an x in each of the environments created in the loop as you showed with `get`, they were created but not evaluated. all the exes are evaluated **first** when you evaluate one of the 10 adders. run the function with `force` in the linked question to see the difference

Comment: @rawr So when the `x`'s are evaluated for the first time, where do they look to get their values? All the explanations say that they look at the last value of the `lapply` loop. However, when the first adder is called the `lapply` loop is already over, so there must be a link somehow between the `adder`'s environment and the `lapply` loop. I hope to ask what that link is.

Comment: @Anh `lapply` creates it's own environment. It's basically running a `for` loop for you. It's kind of like `for(x in 1:10) add(x)`. All the adders then reference that same `x` indexing variable. If you set `add <- function(x) {print(parent.frame());function(y) x + y}` and then run the `lapply` you can see they all have a common calling parent frame.

Comment: @MrFlick That's very helpful. I tried `add <- function(x) {
  print(parent.frame())
  print(environment())
  function(y) x + y
}`, which shows that they share parent frame (i.e., the `lapply` environment), but have different `environment()` of their own. Is it correct to think that by adding `force(x)`, we force the evaluation of `x` in adders' own environments, which is where they will look first even before the `parent.frame`?

Comment: @MrFlick Also, why do the `adders` search for `x` in the `parent.frame` but not in the `parent.environment`? Is that how functions are supposed to work?

Comment: @Anh So this is a bit tricky because the parent frame and the parent environment aren't the same thing. The arguments you pass to a function are evaluated in the calling environment (parent frame). But other variables are evaluated in the parent environment. So each of the adders receive a promise for the value of `x` from the calling frame in their own environment, but without `force()`, this promise isn't evaluated. Functions don't search for variables in the calling environment (parent frame) by default. It's tricky because in R code you can't "see" a promise without evaluating it.