# Can you more clearly explain lazy evaluation in R function operators?

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, environments

If I create a function as follows:

```
what_is_love <- function(f) {
  function(...) {
    cat('f is', f, '\n')
  }
}
```

And call it with `lapply`:  `funs <- lapply(c('love', 'cherry'), what_is_love)`

I get unexpected output:

```
> funs[[1]]()
f is cherry
> funs[[2]]()
f is cherry
```

But note that this is not the case when you do not use `lapply`:

```
> f1 <- what_is_love('love')
> f2 <- what_is_love('cherry')
> f1()
f is love
> f2()
f is cherry
```

What gives?

I know that `funs <- lapply(c('love', 'cherry'), what_is_love)` can be written out more fully:

```
params <- c('love', 'cherry')
out <- vector('list', length(params))
for (i in seq_along(params)) {
  out[[i]] <- what_is_love(params[[i]])
}
out
```

But when I browse in, I see that both functions have their own environment:

```
Browse[1]> out[[1]]
function(...) {
    cat('f is', f, '\n')
  }
<environment: 0x109508478>
Browse[1]> out[[2]]
function(...) {
    cat('f is', f, '\n')
  }
<environment: 0x1094ff750>
```

But in each of those environments, `f` is the same...

```
Browse[1]> environment(out[[1]])$f
[1] "cherry"
Browse[1]> environment(out[[2]])$f
[1] "cherry"
```

I know the answer is "lazy evaluation", but I'm looking for a bit more depth... how does `f` end up re-assigned across both environments?  Where does `f` come from?  How does R lazy evaluation work under the hood in this example?

-

*EDIT:* I'm aware of [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129902) on lazy evaluation and functionals, but it just says the answer is "lazy evaluation" without explaining how the lazy evaluation actually works.  I'm seeking greater depth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explain a lazy evaluation quirk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129902/explain-a-lazy-evaluation-quirk)

Comment: lapply no longer behaviors this way in R-3.2.0.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you do

```
what_is_love <- function(f) {
  function(...) {
    cat('f is', f, '\n')
  }
}
```

the inner function creates an enclosure for `f`, but the catch is that until you actually *use* a variable passed to a function, it remains a "promise" and is not actually evaluated. If you want to "capture" the current value of `f`, then you need to force the evaluation of the promise; you can use the `force()` function fo this.

```
what_is_love <- function(f) {
  force(f)
  function(...) {
    cat('f is', f, '\n')
  }
}
funs <- lapply(c('love', 'cherry'), what_is_love)

funs[[1]]()
# f is love 
funs[[2]]()
# f is cherry
```

Without `force()`, `f` remains a promise inside both of the functions in your list. It is not evaluated until you call the function, and when you call the function that promise is evaluated to the last known value for `f` which is "cherry."

As @MartinMorgran pointed out, this behavior has changed in R 3.2.0. From the [release notes](http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS)

> Higher order functions such as the apply functions and Reduce()
>         now force arguments to the functions they apply in order to
>         eliminate undesirable interactions between lazy evaluation and
>         variable capture in closures.  This resolves PR#16093.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detail.  Would you be able to explain a bit more how R promises work under the hood?

Comment: You never really get to work with promises directly in R code because as soon as you touch them, they disappear. If you want to know how they are implemented, you'll have to read the [R source](https://github.com/wch/r-source). There's a bit more information about them in Hadley's discussion on [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)

Comment: You might also be interested in the [pryr](https://github.com/hadley/pryr) package which has functions like `promise_info()` to help extract information about promises.