# How can I attach a list of custom color palettes to a list of ggplot objects without printing each plot object to the screen?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, rendering, color-palette

I have a data frame in R in which several of the columns are factors.  I'd like to create a series of bar charts showing the relative sizes of each of the factor levels.  I want to associate my own customized color palettes to each of the factors, and then customize the final layout of all of the bars and legends using the [gridExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/gridExtra.pdf) package.

I wrote a an example script which I think should achieve that, however, I obtained a rather surprising result:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grDevices)
library(gridExtra)

# Define some dummy data and put it in a data frame
fruit <- factor(c("apple", "orange", "pear", "pear", "pear",
                  "orange", "apple", "apple", "apple", "pear"))
cheese <- factor(c("cheddar", "mozarella", "gruyere", "gruyere", "gouda",
                   "parmesan", "gruyere", "gouda", "mozarella", "cheddar"))
mydata <- data.frame(fruit, cheese)
mydata$dummy <- 0

# Define some custom color schemes
foodclrs <- list()
# Plot the fruit factor in shades of red
h <- c(0.0,  0.0,  0.0)
s <- c(0.95, 0.85, 0.45)
v <- c(0.45, 0.85, 0.95)
foodclrs[[1]] <- hsv(h, s, v)
# Plot the cheese factor in shades of green
h <- c(0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33)
s <- c(0.95, 0.93, 0.85, 0.69, 0.45)
v <- c(0.45, 0.69, 0.85, 0.93, 0.95)
foodclrs[[2]] <- hsv(h, s, v)

# Create vectors with individualized text for each plot
bsiz=20
fillvars <- c("fruit", "cheese")
xlabels <- c("Fruits", "Cheeses")
lgdlabels <- c("Types of Fruit", "Types of Cheese")

# Generate a list of plots
plots <- list()
for (ii in 1:2) {
  plots[[ii]] <- ggplot(data=mydata) + 
    geom_bar(aes_string(x="dummy", fill=fillvars[ii]),
             position=position_stack(reverse=TRUE)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=foodclrs[[ii]], drop=FALSE) +
    theme_bw(base_size=bsiz) +
    labs(x=xlabels[ii], y="") + 
    theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank()) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title=lgdlabels[ii])) +
    coord_flip()
#  print(plots[[ii]])
}

# Print the plots on my own custom-shaped grid
print(grid.arrange(plots[[1]], plots[[2]], ncol=1, nrow=2))
```

The output of the script looks like this:
[image: Incorrect output--both bar charts are in shades of green, but the top one should be in shades of red.]

This is not what I was expecting: the color palette for the upper bar chart should have been a range of shades of red.  It seems that, although I originally defined the plot object `plots[[1]]` to have a red color palette associated with it, when I actually went to print it, either R or ggplot2 (I'm not sure which) decided to use the most recent color palette instead; i.e., the one associated with `plots[[2]]`.

Now here's the weird part.  If I uncomment the print statement in the `for` loop, I get two individual plots which are rendered in the correct color scheme (for brevity, I do not bother to include either of them here), and, even more interestingly, the combined bar chart object inside the `grid.arrange()` function now also displays the correct color scheme:
[image: Correctly colored plots, using workaround technique.]

While I am happy to have stumbled across this little workaround, now I'm curious: why does it even work in the first place?

That is to say, how is it that calling the "print" statement just at the correct moment inside of the `for` loop causes a color palette to become permanently attached to each ggplot object, when otherwise it would not?

What's really going on here, "underneath the hood", so to speak?  And also, is there a less kludgy way that I could correct the problem?  For example, is there some other function that I could call instead of `print()`, to get the color palette to attach correctly to each plot object, without creating a bunch of individual "dummy" plots that I don't actually need?

Comment: you could store grobs instead of plots, using `ggplotGrob()`.

Comment: Based upon your profile, it appears that you are actually the main author and maintainer of the [gridExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/gridExtra.pdf) package?  Thanks for taking the time to respond; I know you must be very busy!  FWIW, I think I actually prefer your suggestion to use the ``ggplotGrob()`` function, even more than I like your official answer--it seems simpler and cleaner than encapsulating the ggplot call within a function and using purrr::pmap() to implement the loop.  However, I did upvote both of them, since both ways seemed like valid solutions.

Answer (score 3):

ggplot2 isn't very good with scoping. A possible workaround is to wrap things in a function, but even then I was surprised to need force(),

```
f <- function(var, fill, xlab, lab){
  force(fill)
  ggplot(data=mydata) + 
    geom_bar(aes_string(x="dummy", fill=var),
             position=position_stack(reverse=TRUE)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=fill) +
    theme_bw(base_size=bsiz) +
    labs(x=xlab, y="") +
    theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank()) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title=lab)) +
    coord_flip()
}

pl <- purrr::pmap(.f = f, 
                  .l = list(var=fillvars, fill=foodclrs,
                            xlab=xlabels,lab=lgdlabels))

grid.arrange(grobs=pl, nrow=2)
```

Comment: Based on the fact that you enclosed the call to ``ggplot()`` inside a function, and then furthermore needed to use [``force()``](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/force.html), I suspect the weird behavior in my example is due to some kind of quirk of [lazy evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733257/can-you-more-clearly-explain-lazy-evaluation-in-r-function-operators).  Perhaps there's something inside the ``ggplot`` object which is normally evaluated lazily, and the reason the ``print()`` function fixes the problem is that it somehow forces an evaluation?

Comment: Either way, thanks for this; I was unaware previously that R implements lazy evaluation; trying to understand what the ``force()`` function is actually doing in this example lead me down a path toward reading up on some of the more obscure / advanced details about how R works.

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation for what's going on under the hood**: You specified your scale values as `foodclrs[[ii]]`. All the plot objects were evaluated at the end of the loop with the current (i.e. last) value of `ii`.

**Workaround 1**: Assuming you know beforehand how many colours you need from each palette, one possible workaround is to name all of them explicitly in a single combined palette:

```
combined.foodclrs <- c(foodclrs[[1]][seq_along(levels(fruit))], 
                       foodclrs[[2]][seq_along(levels(cheese))])
names(combined.foodclrs) <- c(levels(fruit), levels(cheese))

> combined.foodclrs
    apple    orange      pear   cheddar     gouda   gruyere mozarella  parmesan 
"#730606" "#D92121" "#F28585" "#087306" "#10B00C" "#24D921" "#4DED4A" "#87F285"
```

You can then use the combined palette in the loop & get correct colours in each plot:

```
plots <- list()
for (ii in 1:2) {
  plots[[ii]] <- ggplot(data=mydata) + 
    geom_bar(aes_string(x="dummy", fill=fillvars[ii]),
             position=position_stack(reverse=TRUE)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=combined.foodclrs, drop=FALSE) + #one combined palette
    theme_bw(base_size=bsiz) +
    labs(x=xlabels[ii], y="") + 
    theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank()) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title=lgdlabels[ii])) +
    coord_flip()
}

print(grid.arrange(plots[[1]], plots[[2]], ncol=1, nrow=2))
```

**Workaround 2**: As per @baptiste's comment, you can store them using grobs:

```
plots <- list()
for (ii in 1:2) {
  p <- ggplot(data=mydata) + 
    geom_bar(aes_string(x="dummy", fill=fillvars[ii]),
             position=position_stack(reverse=TRUE)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=foodclrs[[ii]], drop=FALSE) +
    theme_bw(base_size=bsiz) +
    labs(x=xlabels[ii], y="") + 
    theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank()) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title=lgdlabels[ii])) +
    coord_flip()
  plots[[ii]] <- ggplotGrob(p)
}

print(grid.arrange(plots[[1]], plots[[2]], ncol=1, nrow=2))
```

[image: plot]

(Output is the same for both methods)

Comment: I'm not such a huge fan of workaround #1, since it seems to create an unnecessary  coupling between the two plots that shouldn't really need to exist.  However, workaround #2 is just the type of thing that I was looking for--very clean and simple; gets the job done with a minimum of changes from the original design.  It also got me reading about what a ``grob`` object is (as opposed to a plot object) in the first place.