# R does not report error when an argument of a function is not provided but used for subsetting a vector

Tags: r, function, arguments, parameter-passing

Why there is no error reported when b is not supplied but required inside the function? Thanks!

```
f2 <- function(a,b) {a[b]}; f2(a=rep(1, 2))
```

I understand that there is no error in this function:

```
f <- function(x) {
  10
}
f(stop("This is an error!"))
```

due to lazy evaluation
But this

```
f <- function(x) {
  force(x)
  10
}
f(stop("This is an error!"))
```

or this

```
f <- function(x) {
  x
  10
}
f(stop("This is an error!"))
```

will produce an error. Because in both cases x is ***used*** within the function. Both the above two examples are from http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html. Since b is also ***used*** within f2, should it be necessary to add force inside f2? Thanks!

Comment: Simpler version, same issue - `f2 <- function(a,b) {a[b]}; f2(a=1)`

Comment: I'm guessing this is some lazy evaluation quirk that I don't fully understand since if you `debug(f2)` you can see that `b` is returned from `ls()` inside the function's environment. `f2 <- function(a,b) {a[force(b)]}; f2(a=1:2)` also fails once `?force` is used with a '*argument "b" is missing*" error. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733257/can-you-more-clearly-explain-lazy-evaluation-in-r-function-operators

Comment: But I think in the link above, the original function f is not **used**. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733257/can-you-more-clearly-explain-lazy-evaluation-in-r-function-operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x[b]` returns (a duplicate of) `x` if `b` is missing. From the R source:

```
static SEXP VectorSubset(SEXP x, SEXP s, SEXP call)
{
    R_xlen_t stretch = 1;
    SEXP indx, result, attrib, nattrib;

    if (s == R_MissingArg) return duplicate(x);
```

https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ec2e89f38a208ab02449b706e13f278409eff16c/src/main/subset.c#L169

From the documentation, in which 'empty' means 'missing', not `NULL`:

> An empty index selects all values: this is most often used to replace all the entries but keep the attributes.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the `[` function, not lazy evaluation.  You'll get an error if you do the following:

```
f3 <- function(a,b) {a+b}; f3(a = 1)
```

Note that since b is not defined, R is interpreting it as if it didn't exist.  Try doing:

```
a <- c(1,1) 
a[]
```

It seems that the subsetting function ( `[` ) actually takes `...` as a parameter.  I.e., specifying indices to subset are optional.

Comment: Thanks! How about a <- c(1, 1); a[b] without defining b? This will cause an error because b is not defined. But why it is different within a function?

Comment: Again, compare what happens when you do this: `f4 <- function(a, ...) {a+...}; f4(1); f4(1,1); f4(1, c(1,1))`.  For the subset function, indices are optional (...).  When you call `f2` as above, R searches for a variable `b` in the environment, but since it can't match anything, it performs the function with just `a`.  This doesn't work in my `f3` example, because addition requires two variables by definition.

Comment: @DavidKlotz - but `b` does exist in the environment. `debug(f2); f2(a=1)` then `exists("b")` returns `TRUE`. So it exists but is not evaluated, right?

Comment: It's defined in the function call, but it's still missing: `f2 <- function(a,b) {print(missing(a)); print(missing(b)); a[b]}; f2(a=rep(1, 2))`

Comment: I see, thanks both! Sometimes I might forget to include the second variable b when calling function f2. Is it the best way to always use f <- function(a, b){ a[force(b)] } whenever I am subsetting inside a function for guarding against this risk?

Comment: Everything correct here except the part about `...`. If `...` was involved, `\`[\`(a, i = 1, foo = 1)` would work.

Comment: The best way is to explicitly check for missingness: `f <- function(a, b) if (missing(b)) stop('b is missing.') else a[b]`

Comment: Good point, @Roland.  So what's really going on is that the source code for the subset function (quoted by @Hugh) explicitly deals with the case of a missing or empty index.