# Fill a data table by matching column values from onother table (lookup table), and interpolate on another variable

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a very long table with data in R, with some key columns and a lookup table with the same key columns and some extra variables. I want to select from the lookup table, a subset based on the same keys and fill a new column in the data table by interpolating on a common variable.

I try to give a simplified example:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(A = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                   B = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
                   C = rep(c(0.15, 0.22, 0.3),3))
data
#    A B    C
# 1: A 1 0.15
# 2: A 1 0.22
# 3: A 1 0.30
# 4: B 1 0.15
# 5: B 1 0.22
# 6: B 1 0.30
# 7: C 2 0.15
# 8: C 2 0.22
# 9: C 2 0.30

look <- data.table(A = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                   B = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
                   C = rep(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3),3),
                   D = c(10, 20, 30, 11,22,33,12,24,36))
look
#    A B   C  D
# 1: A 1 0.1 10
# 2: A 1 0.2 20
# 3: A 1 0.3 30
# 4: B 1 0.1 11
# 5: B 1 0.2 22
# 6: B 1 0.3 33
# 7: C 2 0.1 12
# 8: i 2 0.2 24
# 9: C 2 0.3 36
```

I want for a matching `A` and `B` columns to use `look$C` and `look$D` and create a new `data$D` column by interpolating based on the `data$C`.

I have a for loop that for each matching A, B combination creates a subset `matched` from `look` runs `f <- approxfun(look$C, look$D)` and apply it `data[ A == 'A' & B == 1, D := f(C) ]`.

so in one iteration will be like

```
f <- approxfun(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), c(10, 20, 30) )
f(c(0.15, 0.22, 0.3))
## and the data table will become
data
#    A B    C  B
# 1: A 1 0.15 15
# 2: A 1 0.22 22 
# 3: A 1 0.30 30
# 4: B 1 0.15
# 5: B 1 0.22
# 6: B 1 0.30
# 7: C 2 0.15
# 8: C 2 0.22
# 9: C 2 0.30
```

The problem is that the `nrow(DATA) > 6000000` and `nrow(look) > 20000`, and it has to be done for 3 new columns, and the iteration have been running for over a day now. So I need a more efficient approach.

Probably there is a better way with `data.table` or `dlpyr`, but I haven't managed to formulate one.

And for some context:

In my field, it is common practice, to work with observations and equivalent modelled values, used for reference. We can run a model for each observation, or a range of values. Some of the common variables, between observations and model can be exact, and hopefully only one close enough, and can be interpolated from the modelled values.

In this case, I work with a 30 years dataset with resolution of 1 minute, the usable observations are currently > 6000000. The modelled values, for now, are just monthly climatological variations > 27000. In the future, I expect the modelled values to be much more, with a finer time step, so the matching and interpolation problem will be a major bottleneck in the analysis.

Solution:

@thothal method gave me the exact results as my first approach, with the iterative evaluation. The dplyr didn't, although, my data are complex, and maybe I miss something in the implementation. From ~2 hours, I got to just some seconds! Thanks to everybody for your suggestions, you gave me some very useful insights for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me drop in a `data.table` solution:

```r
## 1. Create an `approxfun` for each `A/B` combination

## The + 0 trick is necessary b/c otherwise data.table does not evaluate C, D
## while creation and thus keeps just the last chunk of it 

(fns <- look[, .(f = list(approxfun(C + 0, D + 0))), .(A, B)])
#    A B             f
# 1: A 1 <function[1]>
# 2: B 1 <function[1]>
# 3: C 2 <function[1]>

## 2. Join it to data and apply the function
data[fns, .(A, B, C, D = Map(\(f, x) f(x), f, C)), on = .(A, B)]
#    A B    C    D
# 1: A 1 0.15   15
# 2: A 1 0.22   22
# 3: A 1 0.30   30
# 4: B 1 0.15 16.5
# 5: B 1 0.22 24.2
# 6: B 1 0.30   33
# 7: C 2 0.15   18
# 8: C 2 0.22 26.4
# 9: C 2 0.30   36

## w/o Map you would do:
## data[fns, on = .(A, B)][, .(C, f[[1]](C)), .(A, B)]
```

---

Admittedly, the `+ 0` trick is ugly and if somebody knows a more canonical way to solve it, I am very happy to hear, b/c leaving it out won't work (most likely b/c of lazy evaluation):

```r
data[look[, .(f = list(approxfun(C, D))), .(A, B)], 
     .(A, B, C, D = Map(\(f, x) f(x), f, C)), on = .(A, B)]
#    A B    C    D
# 1: A 1 0.15   18 <<- always approxfun(c(.1, .2, .3), c(12, 24, 26))
# 2: A 1 0.22 26.4
# 3: A 1 0.30   36
# 4: B 1 0.15   18
# 5: B 1 0.22 26.4
# 6: B 1 0.30   36
# 7: C 2 0.15   18
# 8: C 2 0.22 26.4
# 9: C 2 0.30   36
```

Comment: Tried this sevelat times, before switching to tidyverse. Also no need of `Map`, just good old `f[[1]](C)` should work as the `f` is the within each group

Comment: Well, no. If you want `f[[1L]]` to work, you would need to specify another `groupby` argument in the last call (then it is equivalent) `data[fns, .(A, B, C, D = f[[1L]](C)), on = .(A, B)]` uses **always** the first function (as instructed).

Comment: I still try to validate the different approaches, as my original data are more complex. In these results, each element of the new column is in a list of length one. And surprising, it seems a little slower than the 'dplyr'.

Comment: `force()` works instead of `+ 0`; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733257/can-you-more-clearly-explain-lazy-evaluation-in-r-function-operators) (comment not made with any authority since I'm still to learn about R programming!)

Comment: Secondly, is there a case for `data[fns, D := Map(\(f, x) f(x), f, C), on = .(A, B)]`, to avoid a copy of the full data, and to do a left instead of a right-join (preserving any unmatched rows)?

Comment: @Todo Yes, I am familiar with `data.table`, so I actually use `:=` in my application to mutate data in-place.

Comment: Well, `force` was my first idea, but did not work out: `data[look[, .(f = list(approxfun(force(C), force(D)))), .(A, B)], .(A, B, C, D = Map(\(f, x) f(x), f, C)), on = .(A, B)]
` shows still the wrong values.

Comment: i used `f[[1]]` in another piped call with .by, that is what i meant to say

Comment: @thothal Oh I see, and I now get what you mean by "keeps the last chunk". Thank you!

Comment: Can you please give an example of this formulation? I use very regular `data.table`, but I am unfamiliar with these syntax and concepts. My data processing needs are not so extended.

Answer (score 1):

couldn't think of a `data.table` solution. Here is a tidyverse solution:

```
look %>%
    group_by(A, B) %>%
    summarise(fun = list(approxfun(C,D)), .groups = 'keep') %>%
    right_join(nest(data, .by = c(A,B)), by = join_by(A, B))  %>%
    reframe(C = data[[1]]$C, D = fun[[1]](C))

# A tibble: 9 × 4
  A         B     C     D
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1  0.15  15  
2 A         1  0.22  22  
3 A         1  0.3   30  
4 B         1  0.15  16.5
5 B         1  0.22  24.2
6 B         1  0.3   33  
7 C         2  0.15  18  
8 C         2  0.22  26.4
9 C         2  0.3   36
```

Comment: I tried this and may work, how do I retain the rest of the `data` columns?

Comment: @ThanasisN Cbind this dataset to your original dataset. ie pull D and cbind it to your original dataset

Answer (score 1):

Here I do the interpolation by hand. This might be faster, especially if you have a `data.table` or SQL backend.

This could be applied to a `data.table` data frame if you have `dtplyr` installed. Of course, the `C_below`, `D_below`, `C_above`, and `D_above` variables could be dropped at the end; I retained them so that it's clearer what's going on.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

data <- tibble(A = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
               B = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
               C = rep(c(0.15, 0.22, 0.3), 3))

look <- tibble(A = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
               B = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
               C = rep(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3),3),
               D = c(10, 20, 30, 11,22,33,12,24,36))


below <-
  data |>
  left_join(look, join_by("A", "B", x$C >= y$C),
            suffix = c("", "_below"),
            relationship = "many-to-many") |>
  group_by(A, B, C) |>
  filter(C_below == max(C_below)) |>
  rename(D_below = D) |>
  ungroup()

above <-
  data |>
  left_join(look, join_by("A", "B", x$C <= y$C),
            suffix = c("", "_above"),
            relationship = "many-to-many") |>
  group_by(A, B, C) |>
  filter(C_above == min(C_above)) |>
  rename(D_above = D) |>
  ungroup()

res <-
  below |>
  inner_join(above, by = join_by(A, B, C)) |>
  mutate(D = case_when(C_below == C_above ~ D_below,
                       .default = D_below + 
                         (D_above - D_below)/(C_above - C_below) * 
                         (C - C_below))) 

res
#> # A tibble: 9 × 8
#>   A         B     C C_below D_below C_above D_above     D
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A         1  0.15     0.1      10     0.2      20  15  
#> 2 A         1  0.22     0.2      20     0.3      30  22  
#> 3 A         1  0.3      0.3      30     0.3      30  30  
#> 4 B         1  0.15     0.1      11     0.2      22  16.5
#> 5 B         1  0.22     0.2      22     0.3      33  24.2
#> 6 B         1  0.3      0.3      33     0.3      33  33  
#> 7 C         2  0.15     0.1      12     0.2      24  18  
#> 8 C         2  0.22     0.2      24     0.3      36  26.4
#> 9 C         2  0.3      0.3      36     0.3      36  36
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**An alternative using DuckDB**

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(DBI)

db <- dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())

data <- tibble(A = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
               B = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
               C = rep(c(0.15, 0.22, 0.3), 3)) |>
  copy_to(db, df = _, name = "data", overwrite = TRUE)

look <- tibble(A = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
               B = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2),
               C = rep(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3),3),
               D = c(10, 20, 30, 11,22,33,12,24,36)) |>
  copy_to(db, df = _, name = "look", overwrite = TRUE)

below <-
  data |>
  left_join(look, join_by("A", "B", x$C >= y$C),
            suffix = c("", "_below"),
            relationship = "many-to-many") |>
  group_by(A, B, C) |>
  filter(C_below == max(C_below, na.rm = TRUE)) |>
  rename(D_below = D) |>
  ungroup()

above <-
  data |>
  left_join(look, join_by("A", "B", x$C <= y$C),
            suffix = c("", "_above"),
            relationship = "many-to-many") |>
  group_by(A, B, C) |>
  filter(C_above == min(C_above, na.rm = TRUE)) |>
  rename(D_above = D) |>
  ungroup()

res <-
  below |>
  inner_join(above, by = join_by(A, B, C)) |>
  mutate(D = case_when(C_below == C_above ~ D_below,
                       .default = D_below + 
                         (D_above - D_below)/(C_above - C_below) * 
                         (C - C_below))) |>
  collect()
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-25 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I haven't thought of this approach, you simplified my problem! I try to do it, but `dplyr` complains.  ```! This join would result in more rows than dplyr can handle.
ℹ 3496932277 rows would be returned. 2147483647 rows is the maximum number allowed.
ℹ Double check your join keys. This error commonly occurs due to a missing join key, or an improperly specified join condition.```

Comment: For the actual data, `dplyr` might not be the best approach because a lot of rows are created that are later filtered out. It might be better to use a **lazy table** approach with `data.table` or with (say) DuckDB. I will edit the answer to show how you might use DuckDB.

Comment: I would love to have a go with duckdb. Your example works, but when I try to load my data on duckdb, I get an error for the common column "C": `Failed to register data frame: Binder Error: table "r_dataframe_scan" has duplicate column name "SZA"`

Comment: OK. Duplicate column names would be a problem with `dplyr` too. You may want to `select()` only the columns that are absolutely necessary in your version of `above` and `below`.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, that this is one of the column to be used in the interpolation. In other words, it complains that my 'C' column equivalent, in the example, is a duplicate, so I can not create the 'look' table in duckdb.