# R Curry weirdness

Tags: r, currying, roxygen2, roxygen

I'm seeing strange behavior with the Curry function from library(roxygen). Here's a minimal example:

```
library(roxygen)
library(foreach)

f <- function(x,y,z) { return(x+y+z) }

fns <- list()
foreach(i=c(1:10))  %do% {
  f[[i]] <- Curry(Curry(f,i),i)
}
```

In this case the call

```
f[[1]](0)
```

returns 11. I expect 2.

There are 2 fixes that don't make any sense to me - one is to flatten the loop, as in

```
fns <- list()
fns[[1]] <- Curry(Curry(f,1),1)
fns[[2]] <- Curry(Curry(f,2),2)
...
```

That works. In addition, putting a single function evaluation in the original loops works - as in

```
fns <- list()
foreach(i=c(1:10)) %do% {
  f[[i]] <- Curry(Curry(f,i),i)
  f[[i]](27)
}
```

We then have

```
f[[1]](0) = 2.
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Restating the problem without the dependencies

I assume `Curry` is [defined](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2007-November/047318.html) as

```
Curry<-function(FUN,...) {
  dots<-list(...);
  function(...) do.call(FUN,c(dots,list(...)))}
```

Then

```
f <- function(x,y,z) list(x,y,z)
fns<-vector("list",10)
for(i in 1:10) {fns[[i]]<-Curry(Curry(c,i),i)}
fns[[1]](0)
```

Yields

```
[1] 10  1  0
```

showing that the first argument to `f` was not evaluated until after the completion of the loop.

#### Analysis

This is due to lazy evaluation.

The culprit here is a bit more subtle than [Explain a lazy evaluation quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129902/explain-a-lazy-evaluation-quirk), which is why I waffled on marking as a duplicate.

What's being delayed here is the evaluation of `FUN`

```
CurryF<-function(FUN,...) {
  force(FUN); #needed for nesting Curry
  dots<-list(...);
  function(...) do.call(FUN,c(dots,list(...)))}
```

Now try again

```
for(i in 1:10) {fns[[i]]<-CurryF(CurryF(c,i),i)}
fns[[1]](0)
```

for the expected result

```
[1] 1 1 0
```

Comment: I think this covers it. So the lazy evaluation quirk is not the culprit - in particular, I will see the behavior I explained in both 2.8 and 3.2 (I am not able to check at the moment)?

Comment: Correction - the it is lazy evaluation/binding. So I should not see this behavior in 3.2.