# Lazy evaluation unexpected result in R

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I am following Hadley Wickham's Advanced R, and working through an example on lazy evaluation.

I first create an add function as :

```
> add <- function(x){
+     function(y) x+y
+ }
```

Then I use apply function on it as :

```
adders <- lapply(1:10, add)
```

Now according to the book, due to lazy evaluation in R, when I try,

```
adders[[1]](20)
```

should yield answer as 10 + 20 = 30, but for me it gives the answer 21.

```
> adders[[1]](20)
[1] 21
```

Any suggestions on why is the lazy evaluation not working on expected lines ?

Comment: Lazy evaluation has been changed after R 3.2.0. See here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129902/explain-a-lazy-evaluation-quirk

Comment: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS.Rd#L2748