# Understanding the lazy evaluation example in Advanced R

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to understand the lazy evaluation example in Prof Hadley Wickham's Advanced R. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129902/explain-a-lazy-evaluation-quirk/16130073#16130073) has been asked about the `adder` function example. My question is on the other example. Why the output to the following code is `"a" "x"`? Why is there an `"x"` there? If `x` is only evaluated at line [3], how can it include itself?

```
[1] f <- function(x = ls()) {
[2]   a <- 1
[3]   x
[4] }
[5] f()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `x` is a parameter to the function, it's defined when the function is run. All parameters will show up when you run `ls()` inside a function. A variable can exist before it's evaluated.