# Lazy evaluation example in Advanced R

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

According to lazy evaluation in R (Advanced R by H. Wickham P.85), the following code should return 20, however I get the return equal to 11.  Did I misunderstand anything?

```
add <- function(x) {

function(y) x + y

}

adders <- lapply(1:10, add)
adders[[1]](10)
```

Comment: You misread the book. `adders[[1]](10)` is expected to return 11 ([book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments)), whereas `adders[[10]](10)` is expected to return 20. More detail: Expanding the `lapply` statement, adders[[1]]` is the same as `add(1)`, which returns `function(y) y + 1`. You're then calling that function with `y = 10`, so the result is `10 + 1 = 11`.

Comment: I believe you want to read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129902/explain-a-lazy-evaluation-quirk